# why do I have to extend S***Activity with HoloEverywhere?

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

HoloEverywhere seems to work without extending Sherlock classes. Why do I have to change the imports?
I've just added: `android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme.Sherlock"`
in the manifest  tag and the theme seems to work on the emulator (Android 2.2).

Instructions say:

> Extend the Activities from com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere.sherlock.S***Activity

**My Question**

1. Is it a must or an alternative way of applying Holo theme individually?
2. Does extending the activity from com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere.sherlock.S***Activity also add ActionbarSherlock to the Activity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a complete Holo theme port to pre-honeycomb devices, you must extend these classes. If not, some simple controls like `EditText` or similars will be displayed with holo theme, but others more complex like `Dialog`s will not be holo-styled.

Comment: what does "complete" mean? It seems buttons are ok, check boxes too, background... at least in the emulator, I will try later with a real device.

Comment: I see, ProgressDialog for example is not displayed with Holo theme, I have to use `com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere.app.ProgressDialog` instead. Perfect answer, thank you, and thanks for the question edit also!

Comment: Yes, you're right, additionally you should use `com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere.widget.*` classes instead of android ones :)